# Example on ToggleButton

Tags: android, togglebutton

I am developing an application using a toggle button, I entered 1 or 0 in `EditText`. When button is clicked, the toggle button has to change if I enter 1 the toggle button shows `TOGGLE ON`, if I enter 0 the toggle button has to show `TOGGLE OFF`. I am unable to get toggle values when the button is clicked.

**My code is:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  String editString="";

  Button btn;
  EditText ed;
  ToggleButton toggle;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    ed  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed);
    toggle = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggBtn);

    editString = ed.getText().toString();

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        toggle.toggle();
        if(editString.equals("1")){

          toggle.setTextOff("TOGGLE ON");

        }
        else if(editString.equals("0")){

          toggle.setTextOn("TOGGLE OFF");

        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**xml file:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:orientation="vertical">

 <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ed"/>
 <Button  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/btn"
         android:text="Summit"/>
  <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggBtn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="center"
         />
```

Comment: thank you but it changed when button clicked second time on words and every time changing toggle button without enter value in edit text when clicked button

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just remove the line `toggle.toggle();` from your click listener `toggle()` method will always reset your toggle button value.

And as you are trying to take the value of `EditText` in string variable which always remains same as you are getting value in `onCreate()` so better directly use the `EditText` to get the value of it in your `onClick` listener.

Just change your code as below its working fine now.

```
  btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       //toggle.toggle();
            if ( ed.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

                toggle.setTextOff("TOGGLE ON");
                toggle.setChecked(true);
            } else if ( ed.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {

                toggle.setTextOn("TOGGLE OFF");
                toggle.setChecked(false);

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You should follow the Google guide;

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // The toggle is enabled
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
        }
    }
});
```

You can check the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try this Toggle Buttons

test_activity.xml

```
<ToggleButton 
android:id="@+id/togglebutton" 
android:layout_width="100px" 
android:layout_height="50px" 
android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:onClick="toggleclick"/>
```

Test.java

```
public class Test extends Activity {

private ToggleButton togglebutton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    togglebutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
}

public void toggleclick(View v){
    if(togglebutton.isChecked())
        Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Please have a look at material components here https://material.io/components/buttons/android#toggle-button
There is a section for toggle button which should be use instead of the oudated answer below.

**Old Answer** ( not recommended anymore)

Move this

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     editString = ed.getText().toString();
```

inside `onClick`

Also you change the state of the toogle button whether its `0` or `1`

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:text="Switch" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/togglebutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:onClick="onToggleClicked"
        android:textOff="Vibrate off"
        android:textOn="Vibrate on" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText ed;
    Switch sb;
    ToggleButton tb;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        sb = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        tb = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String s = ed.getText().toString();
         if(s.equals("1")){

             tb.setText("TOGGLE ON");
             tb.setActivated(true);
             sb.setChecked(true);

         }
         else if(s.equals("0")){

             tb.setText("TOGGLE OFF");
             tb.setActivated(false);
             sb.setChecked(false);

    }
        
    }
     }
```

Snaps

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you but it changed when button clicked second time on words and every time changing toggle button without enter value in edit text when clicked button

Comment: @user3081942 i din't understand your comment

Comment: @user3081942 your problem is your change the state of toogle buttom whethere its `1` or `0`. So it always changes the state

Comment: @user3081942 check the edited post for both switch and toggle button

Answer (score 0):

I think what are attempting is semantically same as a radio button when 1 is when one of the options is selected and 0 is the other option.

I suggest using the radio button provided by Android by default.

Here is how to use it-
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/

and the android documentation is here-

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    editString = ed.getText().toString();
    if(editString.equals("1")){

        toggle.setTextOff("TOGGLE ON");
        toggle.setChecked(true);

    }
    else if(editString.equals("0")){

        toggle.setTextOn("TOGGLE OFF");
        toggle.setChecked(false);

    }
}
```

Comment: @user3081942 Just change this code. and put comment on toggle.toggle();