# Best way to get collect pounds or kilos in android from user?

Tags: android

I am going to write a BMI app and I would like to allow the user to enter weight and height in either U.S. units or metric. I am not sure what is the best way to go about this because I would also like to be able for the user to save their preference. Should I use a switch widget? Thanks in advance. Also not sure if I am asking in the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Radio Buttons](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html) to get the user preference.

Save the user preference in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: Yes that makes sense! I have an iOS background so I am new to Android.

Answer (score 0):

you can use toggle button   in android to switch kilos to pound if you want good ui use this link for toggle button [Example on ToggleButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277490/example-on-togglebutton)

Comment: I went with radio buttons but for the future I will look into ToggleButton.